# Setting the TurtleBot odom_linear_scale_correction parameter

Tags: calibration, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I was attempting to calibrate my TurtleBot's linear odometry and I noticed there is a parameter called odom_linear_scale_correction in turtlebot_node.py that appears to be designed for this job.  However, there doesn't seem to be any mention of this parameter on the [TurtleBot calibration page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_calibration/Tutorials/Calibrate%20Odometry%20and%20Gyro).

I can tweak the parameter using dynamic_reconfigure and add the final result to my launch file, but I was wondering why this parameter is not covered during the rest of the calibration procedure.  The default value of 1.0 is about 10% off for my TurtleBot.

Thanks!

<b
patrick

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37874/setting-the-turtlebot-odom_linear_scale_correction-parameter/) by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4046 on 2012-07-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe that is because the calibration program currently does only rotation, so the parameters that can be corrected relate to the rotation readings. The linear portion is somewhat alluded to in the [main calibration page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_calibration) under "areas to improve". It is possible that the calibration program does not include this since rotations tend to be more of a problem in differential drive robots.

For my own differential drive robot, I wrote my own calibration program to do linear corrections (but this does not use the laser scan - it calculates correction parameter based on "eyeballing" a 1m run and using the time taken vs the theoretical time)

---

Originally posted by [weiin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1505/weiin/) with karma: 2268 on 2012-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2012-07-04**:
Thanks @weiin!